# Copy Multiple DBF files content to other DBF files

Tags: database, windows, dbf

I have 200 DBF files (related to Windows program) that I need to transfer their content to different DBF files that have the same names.. , i.e. file1.dbf content should be transferred to file1.dbf content from different folder, I need to do that for all 200 files. I can only find manual solution but its slow , I need to do it for all at once. The reason I need to do that is because the files have some protection or I don't get it, if I simply replace them the program will give error realated to db, other easier solution is welcome.

What really happened -
The files are used in accounting software. I have created the backup with backup function from the software, it was done daily automatically. Restore function is protected for free version. I can only manually restore the files, but the backup files work only on the exact software version as protection. The thing is that the software is 100% free as long as you don't update it, I didn't knew that until I selected the update menu option. Now the software is updated but it asks me for license key which is very expensive. I have the backup files, but as the restore function is blocked I can't restore it with the program. I can only replace the files myself from the backup , its a directory that is backed up. The problem is that it has some protection on files itself , they are not recognized but only if I manually edit the files with DBF Manager software, if I open a default software file and paste the content from backup file it works, but I have many files.Now I'm stuck with company documents locked not been able to access it

Thank you

Comment: What is the underlying software that requires the licensing?

Comment: Its called saga and can be downloaded here https://mirror1.sagasoft.ro/programe/SetupC.exe  , its the latest version.